# What Reflection Permission are allowed in Medium Trust?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, medium-trust

I want to ask that which methods/classes are allowed in Medium Trust.
For example, 
whether these methods are allowed?

GetProperties,
GetMethods,
Activator.CreateInstance,
Assembly.Version,
AssemblyName.Name

Please tell me which methods are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

GetMethods and Activator.CreateInstance should be allowed IIRC, whilst AssemblyName and Assembly.Version aren't. I've used the first two methods in Medium-Trust environments and the latter two didn't work.
Best way is just through trial-and-error really. Also might help by using Reflector when you do get stuck, to find out *why* stuff isn't allowed (normally [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, AspNetHostingPermission.High/Full)] attribute on a class somewhere higher up the call stack).

HTH,

Benjamin

Comment: I think this is very frustrating that we are not able to know that which methods are available and which are not?

Answer (score 3):

Tools like [permview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06251f13%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (.NET 1.1 only) or [permcalc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165077%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (.NET 2.0) can help tell you about the security permission demands your assembly or assemblies will require; it's a little easier than doing trial-and-error bases analysis because you might forget to manually exercise a code path that tries to do a security-related demand.

Unfortunately the MSDN documentation doesn't explicitly list the security requirements of every method or property call.